# Error while processing route: ... Assertion Failed: You tried to push data with a type ... but no model could be found with that name

Tags: ember.js, json-api

I've been having some problem with relationships/includes and serializers using Ember with JSONAPI.

I have a route to show a patient's info:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params){
    return this.store.find('patient', params.patient_id);
  }
});
```

And I have this two models :

`patient` :

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend(validations, {
  name : DS.attr('string'),
  email : DS.attr('string'),
  gender : DS.attr('string'),
  birthDate : DS.attr('date'),
  description : DS.attr('string'),
  anamnesis : DS.belongsTo('anamnesis')
});
```

and `anamnesis` :

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  smokes : DS.attr('boolean'),
  drinks : DS.attr('boolean'),
  drugUser : DS.attr('boolean')
});
```

as you can see, I have a one-to-one relationship between them.

Now, i have this JSONAPI response from my Ruby on Rails backend

```
{  
  "data":{  
    "id":"3",
    "type":"patients",
    "attributes":{  
        "name":"paciente 3",
        "gender":"female",
        "email":"teste3@teste.com",
        "birth-date":"2017-06-04T02:59:37.435Z"
    },
    "relationships":{  
      "anamnesis":{  
        "data":{  
          "id":"2",
          "type":"anamneses"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "included":[  
    {  
      "id":"2",
      "type":"anamneses",
      "attributes":{  
        "smokes":null,
        "drinks":null,
        "drug-user":null
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

When trying to serialize the `relationship` and `included` it looks for the `anamnese` (from the backend's response type `anamneses`) model instead of `anamnesis`.

`Error while processing route: ... Cannot read property 'type' of null TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of null`

So I had to create a `PatientSerializer` to fix this problem:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import Ember from 'ember';

export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({
  modelNameFromPayloadKey(payloadKey){
    if(payloadKey === 'anamneses'){
      return 'anamnesis';
    } else {
      return this._super(payloadKey);
    }
  },
  modelNameFromPayloadType(payloadType){
    if(payloadKey === 'anamneses'){
      return 'anamnesis';
    } else {
      return this._super(payloadType);
    }
  },
});
```

I know it might not be the best solution but I can't even try something else beacuse it now shows me this error:

`Error while processing route: ... Assertion Failed: You tried to push data with a type 'anamnese' but no model could be found with that name.`

What I am missing? I am fixing it the wrong way?

Comment: Update your question for patients model file name as `patient`. model file name should be singular

Comment: Done @kumkanillam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Change `anamnesis : DS.belongsTo('anamnesis')` to `anamnesis : DS.belongsTo('anamnese')`.
2. Change model file name `anamnesis` to `anamnese`.
3. You don't need to introduce `Patient` serializer for changing the model name.

The above change will work. have a look at [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/f94c2e94261efdbee5aec921e15dd58d?openFiles=models.anamnese.js%2C)

PS: `find` is deprecated in latest version, consider `findAll`

Comment: Thanks! It did work!

I actually wanted to know how to fix it the "right way" by knowing how Ember parses the response to the model and then customizing it according to my needs.

If you have any documentation or link that could help me understand it, i would really appreciate it!

Comment: You can read more about this, https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/models/customizing-adapters/